# Google Maps API on android device and android emulator not working

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

TL;DR: No error. Smooth run/build. But Google Maps Activity template not running on emulator and device but the Google Maps from the Play Store is running smooth.

I just created a new project from Android Studio using their Google Maps Activity template. My After my project loaded, the only thing I modified was the build.gradle(Module: app) and added this line of code

```
defaultConfig{
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

After that I click Run. The project was successful in build/compile as I can see it already installed on my Android Emulator, Bluestacks, but it is not opening. No errors, no anything. The app just kept on crashing.

Out of desperation, I installed Google Maps from Play Store in my Bluestacks because I thought that if my App is not running then so should the Google Map. But the Google Map runs perfectly. So I thought that the problem is probably on my project. I also tried creating a basic android app then installed it on my emulator because I thought the emulator was the problem but still no luck.

I also installed my app on my android device but still not running. "My Application has stopped working"

Android Studio ver 2.2.3

Latest Bluestacks

I chose the Android Studio Minimum SDK: API 17

Comment: Add your error log here..

Comment: @RishabhMahatha I forgot to say, there's no error upon running the app. Thanks for saying!

Answer (score 0):

This problem came with Oreo. Here's the solution.

1. Press the three dot button below the emulator.
2. Settings
3. OpenGL ES renderer
4. Select SwiftShader

[Emulator for Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugM3l.png)